# HTML validation in Java

Tags: java, validation, dtd

I try to write a HTML validator. At this time I considered the best way is to use a DTD File, because the Validator should complain, if interactive things, like JavaScript are used.
Does anyone know a way, how i can validate a HTML file against a DTD file in Java?
Are there ways with native librarys? I'm also satisfied with external libraries.
thanks in advance

Comment: Try this aproach http://www.edankert.com/validate.html

Answer (score 0):

Word of advice: you cannot really identify all javascript in HTML with accuracy. How precise do you have to be about it? You can have javascript in event handlers, inline and in many other places.

If you are satisfied with non-strict parsing, I suggest [NejoHtml](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net) and [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)